# Drop Down is Clipped in Scrolling Handsontable

Tags: combobox, scrollbar, handsontable, clipping, dropdownbox

I have a Handsontable that is horizontally scrolling. The width is explicitly fixed, the height is auto and the containing DIV has auto overflow.

When a drop down cell is activated, i.e. the drop down container with items is shown, the items list is clipped. I have to scroll down to view all of the items. How can I style the drop down items list such that it appears above the scrollable area?

Here is an example of the clipped drop down:  http://jsfiddle.net/ehLeur99/

Here is the DIV styling:

```
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable" style="width: 210px; height: auto; overflow: auto;"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue with creating new rows overflowing so had to increase and decrease the height of the container div using the appropriate callbacks, it's not ideal but it worked but I'm not sure if it would be any help in this scenario.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I agree with your suggestion as a work-around. I'll definitely take this approach as a worst-case scenario, i.e. if I cannot find a solution within the next week or two. Thanks

Comment: no problem @TotallyHosed , let me know if you find an alternative, I love the handsontable plugin but the css can be quite annoying.